# Boost MPL Placeholders and Lambda

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

I am currently doing some proof on concept samples with boost::mpl and am having some difficulties in understanding how the lambda function enables the use of placeholders.

I realize that I can wrap metafunctions in metafunction classes to enable higher order functions to be able to access the nested apply function, and have realised that you can avoid this effort by using mpl::lambda wrapping the metafunction which allows place holders.

How does this actually work? I am having trouble wrapping my head around what lamda and placeholders actually do under the covers.

Answer (score 13):

See the [Boost.MPL manual](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/metafunctions.html): a placeholder is a metafunction class of the form `mpl::arg<X>`. A metafunction class is a class containing an `apply` metafunction.

```
template <int N> struct arg; // forward declarations
struct void_;

template <>
struct arg<1>
{
    template <
      class A1, class A2 = void_, ... class Am = void_>
    struct apply
    {
        typedef A1 type; // return the first argument
    };
};
typedef arg<1> _1
```

It's the job of `mpl::lambda` to turn placeholder expressions into metafunction classes. This is done by embedding a metafunction class like [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/lambda.html):

```
template<
      typename X
    , typename Tag = unspecified
    >
struct lambda
{
    typedef unspecified type;
};
```

If x is a Placeholder Expression in a general form `X<a1,...an>`, where `X` is a class template and `a1,... an` are arbitrary types, the embedded unspecified type `f` is equivalent to

```
typedef protect< bind<
      quoten<X>
    , lambda<a1>::type,... lambda<an>::type
> > f;
```

otherwise, `f` is identical to `X`. The `apply` metafunction evaluates a lambda expression by accessing the embedded type.

In the MPL [manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/composition-and-argument-binding.html) you can lookup the definitions of `protect`, `bind` and `quote` as well. They are all wrappers around their arguments to delay evaluation as long as possible.

Comment: Clear and concise answer - should have been accepted by the OP.

Comment: Thanks, glad to have been of help!